# How to change the colors of chart.Correlation from PerformanceAnalytics library in R?

Tags: r, graphics, data-visualization

I have an all numerical data frame in `R` (no factors or levels) for which I'm trying to plot the correlation plot with the function `chart.Correlation` from `PerformanceAnalytics` library. Documentation [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/PerformanceAnalytics/versions/1.5.3/topics/chart.Correlation)

The default colors are black and red. I want to be able to change the colors primarily and other attributes if possible.

The docs say that the function takes "any other passthru parameters into pairs." I do not understand this statement. I tried to pass some of the same parameters such as `bg="lightblue"` but absolutely no change.

Any help would be very much appreciate it.

Update!

For what is worth - I was able to get some of the things  wanted with another library which is built on top of `pairs`. Here is the code:

```
library("psych")

pairs.panels(plot_data, 
             hist.col="#00FA9A", 
             show.points=TRUE, 
             stars=TRUE, 
             gap=0.05, 
             pch=".", 
             ellipses=FALSE, 
             scale=FALSE,
             jiggle=TRUE,
             factor=2,
             main="Correlation", 
             col="#ADFF2F", 
             pty="m", 
             font=2)
```

[image]

I still do not know how to change the color of the data points - so there is your chance to get the points.

Answer (score 0):

To change the color of the data points in the pairs.panels function (in psych) look at the example in the help menu:

`pairs.panels(iris[1:4],bg=c("red","yellow","blue")[iris$Species],
  pch=21+as.numeric(iris$Species),main="Fisher Iris data by Species",hist.col="red")`